# Difference between :visited and :active selectors

Tags: html, css

what is the difference between :visited and :active pseudo classes in css ?

I think :active will changed the anchor color when the redirected page is loaded completely.Am I right?

thanks a lot....

Comment: `:active` has focus, `:visited` is in the browser's history.

Comment: `:focus` has focus; `:active` is activated (usually by a mouse-down).

Comment: @Wevah - Ah, I see. Was not aware of `:focus`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:active` is for when the user has *clicked* the element.
`:visited` is for when the user has visited the link before.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes